# how to monitor sound (or sound card) activity?

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio

Is there's a software that runs in the background or something and whenever no sound is detected, launch an application?

To explain: how to check sound card usage? if no app is currently using sound card, then do 'this', else simply keep running in the background.

I guess something that checks every minute or so...

OS: Windows 7 Home.

Comment: What operating system are you using? What do you mean by "no sound", no working sound card, or silence in the room the computer is in? Please edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @terdon, is it any clearer? Please make more suggestions, if not.

Comment: You need to indicate if you're asking about `playback`, or `capture`. Playback is when audio applications are trying to play audio back through the speakers. Capture is when a microphone or other input device provides audio TO the computer. You can theoretically do both, but what you want sounds to be so custom that you'd probably need to write a custom application to begin with.

Comment: @allquixotic I mean about playback. If no playback, run this bat file. Is it too custom?

Comment: There's no easy way to script that. You're going to have to write a program.